# xmlhttp request problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is my JavaScript function for xmlhttp:

```
          var params = "a=" + encodeURIComponent(a) 
           + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(b)
           + "&c=" + encodeURIComponent(c);
var url = "noob.php";

            xmlHttp2.open("POST", url, true);<<<<up till here also no prob,did some testing

            xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = stateChanged2;
             xmlHttp2.send(params);
            }
```

This is noob.php

```
<?php

include('config.inc.php');
include('database.inc.php');
$a = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a'], $con); 
$b = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['b'], $con); 
$c = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['c'], $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (inchat,preference)     values('N','$a$b$c');");

echo mysql_insert_id();

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

All the code of noob.php are working, I tried it with a html form.
So the possible error should lie on:

```
xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = stateChanged2;
xmlHttp2.send(params);
```

1. send parameter failed, I don't know how to test this
2. the string is sent is not recognised by noob.php (somehow - maybe cause the format sent is wrong?)

The problem is the parameter is not inserted into the table. So which of the possible choice above is true?

Comment: Did you ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962348/help-me-fix-a-code-comparison-provided

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: *I don't know how to test this* Have a look at Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/ ... I assume you are the same person who asked the other question. As I said in my comment there we cannot help you much much. You have to do some debugging on your own, we cannot do this for you.

Comment: Your query isn't working. Please post example result.

Answer (score 0):

> All the code of noob.php are working, I tried it with a html form. So
>   the possible error should lie on:

```
xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = stateChanged2; 
xmlHttp2.send(params);
```

This kind of problems most times are easily identified by placing an alert after some suspicious line.

So before you have any doupts about `xmlHttp2.send(params);` firstly place an alert after `xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = stateChanged2;` if the alert does not appear then go where the function `stateChanged2;`  is declared and investigate it again with an alert (most probably the prblem is in that function, there must be an error there);